# How to test Firebase Functions with Cache Control Header on localhost?

Tags: firebase, caching, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to **Cache Control Header** implementation and I need someone to point out any of my mistakes and/or misunderstandings over the cache control effects on Firebase Cloud Functions.

**My understanding & expectation on Cache Control over Firebase Functions**

> When the Cache Control Header has been successfully set using `Express response object` (confirmed by checking from the Chrome's Network
> tab), regardless it is on localhost or production server, the Firebase
> Https Functions (not callable functions) should not be invoked again
> after the first reload until the cache is expired.

Am I right? But after a few rounds of testing, it seems like my cloud function on localhost still consistently get invoked (confirmed by server console logging) regardless the number of refresh on my web browser. Below is my current Http header:

```
**General:**
    Request URL: http://localhost:5005/otk-web-solutions?id=B0Y0jp2x83WVYzWrpg5y
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 304 Not Modified
    Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5005
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response Headers:**
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    cache-control: public, max-age=432000, s-maxage=432000
    content-length: 9688
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    date: Mon, 05 Apr 2021 11:52:20 GMT
    etag: W/"25d8-TxL0Q+ujhzDjys8IJ1mLigY7jT8"
    vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Cookie
    x-powered-by: Express

**Request Headers:**
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.816734993.1603107580; _gid=GA1.1.223745218.1617606982; __atuvc=20%7C12%2C15%7C13%2C23%7C14; __atuvs=606aec5f76521aab00a
    DNT: 1
    Host: localhost:5005
    If-None-Match: W/"25d8-TxL0Q+ujhzDjys8IJ1mLigY7jT8"
    sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36

**Query String Parameters:**
    id: B0Y0jp2x83WVYzWrpg5y
```

**On [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache):**

> You can, though, configure caching behavior for dynamic content. For
> example, if a function generates new content only periodically, you
> can speed up your app by caching the generated content for at least a
> short period of time.
>
> You can also potentially reduce function execution costs because the
> content is served from the CDN rather than via a triggered function.

Could it be that, the cache control header **has no effects on localhost** except on Firebase CDN, which means only when we've deployed it to the production server for the caching to work on the cloud CDN? Is there a right way to implement such test to see the **effectiveness of the cache control header** in helping to save the Firebase Cloud Functions' execution costs?

Please advise, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache) and after checking your test, only if the content is served from the CDN you will be able to save costs.

Even if your request is met with a status code `304 Not Modified`, it seems like you're still making the request and invoking the function if you're not using the Firebase Hosting CDN.

So to make a test to see if you can save costs by not invoking the function many times you should set up [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) and do that same test to see if a response from the CDN invokes the function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean by **setup Firebase Hosting** -- I've setup my Firebase Hosting since day 1 and using the latest version of Firebase Emulators anyway.

Comment: @AntonioOoi Sorry, I said that because if you have Firebase Hosting you use their CDN to test whether the functions get invoked using that compared to the browser cache.

Comment: That means there is no way whatsoever to test the caching on `localhost` right?

Comment: @AntonioOoi You would have to test with the Firebase Hosting CDN. The caching is there in your browser in localhost, but it seems like only if the content is served through the CDN you can save costs because it would not invoke the function.